# How to keep this 4x2 grid from overflowing to the next row?

Tags: css, html

For my assignment, I'm supposed to make 4x2 grid that is bound by a container width:66% and floated right.

I've achieved that but if I resize it a certain way, the cells will flow to the next line. I want to keep it on the same line and be contained by the div containing the rows.

My code:

```css
.container{
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    height: 99%;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}
.floating-box2 {
    float: left;
    width: 21%;
    height: 99%;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#row1 {
  width: 99%;
  height: 195px;
}
#row2 {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <article>
  <div id="row1">
    <div class="floating-box">
      <img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/1.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Robots Replacing Our Future?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="floating-box">
      <img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/2.jpg"></a><a href="www.google.com">The Universe is in Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="floating-box">
      <img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/3.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">New Funding Towards For ICE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="floating-box">
      <img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/4.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Ongoing Refugee Crisis</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="row2">
  <div id="row2">
  <div class="floating-box2"><img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/5.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Oil in 2017</a></div>

  <div class="floating-box2"><img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/6.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Why Travel?</a></div>
  <div class="floating-box2"><img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/7.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Religion Today</a></div>
  <div class="floating-box2"><img src="http://eden.rutgers.edu/~ttb39/8.jpg"><a href="www.google.com">Obamacare Repeal Pulled</a></div>
  </div>
  </article>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's the codepen?

Comment: Look at your HTML and fix all the incorrectly closed `<div>`, `<a>`and `<article>` tags. And then see if you still have the issue.

Comment: Since you are using floats, the content will wrap to a new row as there won't be enough space. You will either need an additional wrapper row div with overflow-x to maintain size or you will need to set the size of the child divs using relative unites to shirk with the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you problem is this:

`row1 width` = 395.297
`div.floating-box` = 23% = 90.906px + 2px + 10px = 102.9px
102.9px * 4 = 411.6px

and 411.6 > 395.297px and because of that it goes down.
You can fix it by removing margin and border or decreasing size of floating-box.

Edit:
of course for big screens it will work fine, because you have a 8% reserve, but on small screens it is not enough. You can also you media query to remove margin only on small screens